# Method with string input, why does unit test does not cover all blocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method which takes a string as an input, checks that it is not null and that the length of the string is greater than zero then returns Enums based on if the string contains another string. (Below showing 5 of the 11 if statements)

```
public static sapActivityEnums CheckString(string input)
{
    if(!input.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        if(input.Contains("DailySap"))
        {
            return sapActivityEnums.Daily;
        }

        if(input.Contains("WeeklySap"))
        {
            return sapActivityEnums.Weekly;
        }

        if(input.Contains("MonthlySap"))
        {
            return sapActivityEnums.Monthly;
        }

        if(input.Contains("QuarterltSap"))
        {
            return sapActivityEnums.Quarterly;
        }

        if(input.Contains("YearlySap"))
        {
            return sapActivityEnums.Yearly;
        }
    }

    return sapActivityEnums.Unassigned;
}
```

The tests that I preform are: empty input, null input,  input string contains condition, input string does not contain condition..

```
[Test()]
public void CheckStringIsNullTest()
{
    string input = null;
    sapActivityEnums expectedResult = sapActivityEnums.Unassigned;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, Util.CheckString(input);
}


[Test()]
public void CheckStringIsEmptyTest()
{
    string input = string.Empty;
    sapActivityEnums expectedResult = sapActivityEnums.Unassigned;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, Util.CheckString(input);
}


[Test()]
public void CheckStringCorrectParmTest()
{
    string input = "WeeklySapReport_07_02_2107_25437865.xlsx";
    sapActivityEnums expectedResult = sapActivityEnums.Weekly;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, Util.CheckString(input);
}



[Test()]
public void CheckStringIncorrectParmTest()
{
    string input = "Weekly_SapReport_07_02_2017_25437865.xlsx";
    sapActivityEnums expectedResult = sapActivityEnums.Unassigned;

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, Util.CheckString(input);
}
```

This gives me a code coverage of 80%.  I'm just courious as to why not all codeblocks are covered.  Do I have to have a test for input sting containing "WeeklySap", "DailySap", etc The full method checks for 10 conditions, so would I need 10 tests?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This clearly isn't your real code, given that it wouldn't compile, and you haven't shown the tests you're using. I'd also expect your code coverage tool to *show* you the areas that aren't covered.

Comment: "Do I have to have a test for input sting containing test1 and another test for string containing test2?" Well they'd be testing different code paths, wouldn't they?

Comment: Just a side note `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))`

Comment: What test framework do you use? At least in mstest there is a color highlighting that shows which blocks are covered and which are not. And that will show you that all the `Return` statements in the `if`s you didn't provide a test for aren't covered.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was not at my machine when posting, so put an example piece of code. The code coverage tool does not show what area wasn't covered, may be an issue with my install but it does not highlight any code paths. Also your two comments come across as very condescending, I apologise that I am not as savvy as you when it comes to coding.

Comment: @Guy Thanks for the tip, I did have this in my actual code but as I wasn't at my machine and was only posting a quick example. Very helpful for others who are not aware

Comment: It's not a matter of being savvy about coding. It's a matter of putting in due diligence before asking a question. If you weren't at your machine, so couldn't ask a good question, that's fine... the answer is to wait until you *can* ask a good question instead of asking a bad one. Bear in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to get you an answer as quickly as possible - it's to build up a repository of good questions and answers. The right way to achieve that goal is to put time into asking your questions.

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm using nunit3 test adapter, not show why but it is not actually highlighting any code paths either covered or not covered. Could be an issue with my installation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I could have and probably should have waited to post, but the post is pretty clear as to what I was asking and easy to follow, apologies if not. What difference would extra lines have made? I stated the test cases and even asked if I would need all conditions for all if statements as I was not aware if I needed to (first time doing unit tests as I am learning).  I came onto stack overflow to first search for an answer then post when I couldn't find one. From someone who is learning your comments were not very constructive, as I said they came across very condescending.

Comment: "What difference would extra lines have made?" They would have shown that you were testing what you thought you were testing, for one thing. Likewise if you'd posted valid code, it would be more likely to be your *actual* code - given that you haven't posted your *actual* code, we can't know what important differences there might be between your actual code and your real code. If you're interested in learning, this is the most important thing you can learn from this question: how to ask better questions.

Comment: That may sound condescending too, but that's possibly because I have a great deal of experience in looking at questions. I know a good question from a bad question. If the only result of you asking this question is knowing that yes, you need to add another test, then that doesn't gain you very much. If instead you get better at reacting to problems, then that's a *much* bigger win IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet You have said that it is a bad question, fine I will know in future not to post generic code to describe an issue, lesson learned. The two questions were: Do I need to test for each if condition? and Do I need separate tests? Others we kind enough and patient enough to read the badly worded question and provide helpful answers and feedback, you on the other hand decided to be condescending. Continued below.

Comment: Yes, I try not to answer bad questions, as it encourages the bad behaviour. Instead, I advise on how to improve the question, and then when the question *is* improved (which it still isn't in this case - you've had plenty of time to improve it, but have chosen not to do so) *then* I add an answer. That way, everyone wins for that question, and hopefully the questioner is encouraged to put in time for their next question too.

Comment: @JonSkeet How about this as an alternative to your comment "Yes, they would be testing different code paths and therefore would need their own tests. For future reference please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. It would be more helpful to post actual code that what you have provided.  If you insist on Good questions being asked then should you also not try to provide good comments?

Comment: I think my comments were entirely reasonable, to be honest. I asked the question you should have been asking yourself ("Would they be testing different code paths?") and suggested how to improve the question. I think we'll have to agree to disagree about who was less respectful of the time and energy of others here...

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually you said "Well they'd be testing different code paths, wouldn't they?" Which is alot more condescending, which is what I have the issue with than "Would they be testing different code paths?" The latter is a perfectly fine comment the former not so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a test for each scenario and a test case to run this. If you're running the test without two test cases then only 1 test is going to be ran in. Also, if you're testing strings that have the same name as your enums you might be interested in trying to parse the string to enum and if that fails return the unassigned enum. Switch is quicker in code but slower to write and introduces more places to look after.

You don't really need to have 10 separate tests. Please take a look at TestCase: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute. One test that is initialized with different test cases could solve your problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. The strings are taken from a user selected file so they are not the same as my Enums. I produced a sting list of the acceptable filenames to test as this is only one part of a validation procedure. Was going to use a switch statement but as I'm doing a contains on the string (as complete file name is not static) I couldn't. I know this is a feature of c# 7.0 but we are not using that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Code coverage executes all tests and memorizes which code lines (or to be more specific which expressions) it has passed while executing.

This passed expressions are your code coverage. To get 100% code coverage your unit tests need to visit all statements in the production sources.